# What does ClassName.ctor>b__11 stand for in dotTrace Profiler?

Tags: c#, profiler, dottrace

While using dotTrace profiler I am getting a lots of calls to `NamespaceName.ClassName.ctor>b__11`
(When I used Equatec profiler on my application I got similar results with the mysterious function being called `NamespaceName.ClassName.<ctor>b__11` ). I first assumed that it is the constructor of the `ClassName` but the break point inside of the constructor of `ClassName` was only hit once.
I am assuming this is auto generated function and if it is how can I find where it gets called? What relation does it have to the constructor of `ClassName` if constructor only gets called once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a lambda declared in the constructor. Did you subscribe to an event in the constructor using the `=>` syntax, or something else that will get called frequently?

When you use a lambda, the C# compiler turns that into a private method, and uses a delegate to that method. (And other fancy tricks if you're doing variable capture.)

Looking at other classes in Reflector, it looks like the C# compiler simply numbers each lambda when it turns them into methods, with the naming convention you've noticed, `<methodName>b__<number>`, just numbering each one as it goes.